# Finding combinatorial occurrences along combination of rows between 2 numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, bioinformatics

I am trying to find a fast **vectorized** (at least partially) solution finding combinatorial occurrence between two 2D numpy array to identified Single Point Polymorphism linkage.
The shape of each array is
**(factors, samples)**
an example for matrix 1 is as follows:

```
array([[0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1.]])
```

and matrix 2

```
array([[1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

I need to find the **total number of occurrence along samples axis for each permutation of 2 factors at the same position of 2 matrix** (order matters because (1,0) count is different from (0,1) count). Therefore the combinations should be [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)] and the final output is (factor, factor) for counts of each occurrence.

For combination (0,0) for instance, we get the matrix

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0., 1]])
```

Because
0 counts (0,0) along row 0 of matrix 1 & row 0 of matrix 2,
1 along row 0 of matrix 1 & row 1 of matrix 2,
0 along row 1 of matrix 1 & row 0 of matrix 2,
1 along row 1 of matrix 1 & row 1 of matrix 2,

Answer (score 2):

With example data

```py
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 1.]])
array2 = np.array([
        [1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])
```

We can count the desired combinations with [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) and [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) to a suitable array

```
c1 = np.array([1-array1, array1]).astype('int')
c2 = np.array([1-array2, array2]).astype('int')
np.einsum('ijk,lmk->iljm', c1, c2).reshape(-1, len(array1), len(array2))
```

Output

```
array([[[0, 1],    # counts for (0,0)
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],    # counts for (0,1)
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 2],    # counts for (1,0)
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 0],    # counts for (1,1)
        [1, 0]]])
```

Checking that the previous results are equal to dot products

```py
import itertools as it

np.array([x @ y.T for x, y in it.product(c1, c2)])
```

Output

```
array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 0]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I realized the solution while trying to derive a manual example for the question, I will just provide that we should solve these by dot products:

```
matrix1_0 = (array1[0]==0).astype('int')
matrix1_1 = (array1[0]==1).astype('int')
matrix2_0 = (array2[1]==0).astype('int')
matrix2_1 = (array2[1]==1).astype('int')

count_00 = np.dot(matrix1_0 , matrix2_0.T)
count_01  = np.dot(matrix1_0 , matrix2_1.T)
count_10  = np.dot(matrix1_1 , matrix2_0.T)
count_11  = np.dot(matrix1_1 , matrix2_1.T)
```

These would correspond to sum of number of occurrence for each combination for each factor along a certain axis (sample axis 1 here).